Efficient way to merge rows in a dataframe that have the same column value?
I have a dataset that contains duplicates that I would like to merge; it looks something like this:
   Name   Type   Profit   Cost   Year
1  A      X      10       5      2012
2  B      X      20       13     2013
3  C      Y      50       29     2013
4  D      Z      10       8      2014

I want to merge rows with the same Type in this case. Is there an efficient way to do this in a way that adds the Profit and Cost of rows with the same Type while keeping the Name and Year of the topmost record?
For example, with the above dataframe, the desired result would be this:
   Name   Type   Profit   Cost   Year
1  A      X      30       18     2012
3  C      Y      50       29     2013
4  D      Z      10       8      2014


I do not understand why A is kept and not B.

I think OP wants the "topmost record".

Well, but it's a contradiction to "merge" imo. I am fearing a data loss, wrong follow-up analysis.

@Friede Yes, "merge" is not the correct word to use here. Summarize or aggregate are probably more appropriate words that come to my mind.

You can use the dplyr package to summarise your data.
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  summarise(
    Name = first(Name),
    Year = first(Year), 
    Profit = sum(Profit),
    Cost = sum(Cost),
   )


data %>% summarise(..., .by=Type) may be better since the result is ungrouped.

Good point, however if data is only grouped by one variable the default behaviour of summarise is to return an ungrouped data.frame anyway.

Equally good point.


Efficient way to merge rows in a dataframe that have the same column value.

You probably mean summarise, not merge.
I suspect dplyr::summarise() to be rather slow. If "[e]fficient way" addresses speed, try
D = read.table(header = TRUE, text =  "  Name   Type   Profit   Cost   Year
               1  A      X      10       5      2012
               2  B      X      20       13     2013
               3  C      Y      50       29     2013
               4  D      Z      10       8      2014")

library(collapse)
D |> 
  fgroup_by(Type) |> 
  fsummarise(Name = Name[1], Year = Year[1], 
             Profit = sum(Profit), Cost = sum(Cost))

  Type Name Year Profit Cost
1    X    A 2012     30   18
2    Y    C 2013     50   29
3    Z    D 2014     10    8

